# Calling method in Jframe from external class and thread to set label values

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, thread-synchronization

I have two classes, one JFrame, and one external class that implements runnable.  The external class I would like to run in its own thread until given an order to stop.  I would also like it to update values on the JFrame in the background in its own thread via a method implemented within its class (or so this is how I thought the most elegant approach would be).

I've made a simple program to illustrate what I'd like done and show that it doesn't work.  From what I understand, the JFrame's values are not updated when called from outside of the EDT.  I keep finding fixes that say to wrap the part of code in which you'd like to change text values in an `invokelater()` call.  However, this STILL doesn't work.  I'm really in a bind, and I'm sure it's something simple, I just can't see why this isn't working.

In this simple example, I have a start button and output in the JFrame.  I instantiate my external class, and start it as a thread in the JFrame class when the start button is pressed.  The thread is in an external class and updates the output until it reaches 5.  It does this by calling a method in the JFrame that calls `setText()` on the output label.

JFrame (I'll omit the automatically generated parts):

```
package javaapplicationtest;

public class JavaTestForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public JavaTestForm() {
    initComponents();
    jtf = new JavaExternClass();
    jtf_thread = new Thread(jtf);
}

/* Method I use outside of this class to update output label */
public void setLabel(int in) {
    final int inf = in;
    System.out.println("Setting output to " + in);

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            output.setText(Integer.toString(inf));
        }
    });
}

/* Start button is pressed */
private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)   {                                      
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            jtf_thread.start();
        }
    });
}   

/* Main entry */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new JavaTestForm().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

/* External class */
private JavaExternClass jtf;
private Thread jtf_thread;
```

My External Class:

```
package javaapplicationtest;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class JavaExternClass implements Runnable {    
    public void run() {
        gui = new JavaTestForm();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            gui.setLabel(i); // Call method to set form output
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JavaTestForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private JavaTestForm gui;
}
```

Comment: *"(I'll omit the automatically generated parts):"*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  `Thread.sleep(1000);`  Don't use that in a Swing/AWT GUI.  Instead use a Swing `Timer`.  Actions within the `Timer` (`actionPerformed(..)`) are automatically on the EDT.

Comment: I see why you mention SSCCE and MCVE now that I read your bio.

Comment: I wrote the SSCCE & helped create the MCVE for the same reason that I link to them often (and write many).  Because preparing an MCVE/SSCCE is both a good debugging technique as well as being a *great* way to communicate a problem to others.  At the moment I have 2 bits of code I'm playing with, one contains a 'piano keyboard' that will allow the user to select an instrument, click a key and hear what that instrument sounds like at that tone.  But I was trying to add ability to load and play MIDI tunes and show the keys being played and run into a problem.  So I've created an MCVE to test ..

Comment: .. ideas.  It has no GUI at all (since the GUI is not relevant to the problem) and just focuses on playing a MIDI sequence while trying to detect the note on/off control codes (which is the problem I have not managed to solve yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a new instance of `JavaExternClass`, you're creating a new instance `JavaTestForm`...how this hasn't ended in a `StackOverflowException` is beyond me at the moment, but the "other" problem is, the instance of `JavaTestForm` in `JavaExternClass` has no relevance to the one create in `main` which is actually the UI which is on the screen.

Instead of having `JavaExternClass` create a new instance of `JavaTestForm`, you should pass a refernce of `JavaTestForm` to it...

```
public class JavaExternClass implements Runnable {   
    private JavaTestForm gui;
    public JavaExternClass(JavaTestForm gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
```

Now, I'm a stick in the mud when it comes to these things, but, I would not like to pass classes around to other classes which have other functionality that the recipient should not know about or have access to, nothing worse then some class some where removing all you components!

Instead, I'd create a `interface` which described the actions which `JavaExternClass` would like to perform and implement this class on `JavaTestForm`, thereby only exposing the functionality that `JavaExternClass` expects and nothing else.

You might also like to take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: I'll check those references out, but in this case, as you pointed out, it was just a really good example of terrible code, and misuse/misunderstanding of fundamental oo principals/semantics.  I've been working too much on this, I think my brain is broken.

Comment: Do you have any input on Andrew Thompson's comment to my original question?  I like this implementation better than using `Timer`s (There are a handful of these classes, and they perform fairly complex communications/operations with external devices).  But I'm relatively unfamiliar with Java, so I don't really know.

Comment: If your intention is to modify the state of the UI on a regular basis, then yes, a Swing `Timer` would be a better choice, as it performs it's tick callbacks within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  If however, you need to wait for some information/perform long running process, then a `SwingWorker` might be better, it allows you to perform operations outside of the EDT, but has support for synchronising updates back to the EDT via the `publish`/`process` methods...